# Enable to get custom field value in product discription page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to show product custom field value in product description page tab

1. first I have created a custom tab with the name of 'Youtube video' in function.php (/wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php)

Here is the code

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
 function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

// Adds the new tab

$tabs['test_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Youtube Video', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 55,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
);

return $tabs;

}
```

And my function content

```
 function woo_new_product_tab_content() {


     $mood = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mood', true);

    if ($mood) { ?>

    <p>Today's Mood: <? echo $mood; ?></p>

    <?php 

      } else { 

       echo "No data found";

      }
  }
```

Both code I have pasted in function.php (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/)

And I have set a custom tab value in product page (please check the first field in bellow image )

[image: customfield image]

But in product page I am unable to get this value!

[image: product page]

please let me know where am I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: There is no variable `$post` inside your function, so you can not access `$post->ID` either.

Comment: @04FS what i suppose to do now ?

Comment: `get_the_ID()` should probably work in that context to get the ID of the current post.

Comment: @04FS yes i can get the id by using this 
$this_page_id = get_the_ID(); echo $this_page_id ;

Comment: but passing the id directly is not working as well 
$mood = get_post_meta($this_page_id , 'Mood', true);

Comment: Is the meta key name really `Mood`, upper case on the first letter? What does a `var_dump($mood);` result in?

Comment: the result was 'string(0) ""   --- yes 'Mood' is the right name , you can check that in screenshoot which i have provided in question

Comment: also i have noticed , the newly added custom field data is not coming , i have used existed one , then the result is 'string(1) "0" 0'  (but i can't change this value 0)